# Force a class to register event

Tags: c#, interface

is it possible to force a class to register an event? I want to validate my properties with a event, which fire if the property isnt valid. In the constructor of the class i want to get an IValid interface, which force all classes to implement the interface (if they want to use my class). So the validation of my properties is safety and the never get invalid values. Or is there a better opportunity?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept an event handler in the constructor if you want:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event Action<string> Bar;
    public Foo(Action<string> initialHandler)
    {
        Bar += initialHandler;
    }
}
```

Now, technically, someone can pass in `null` for `initialHandler`, so you'll need to check for that, but hopefully it helps make it clear to users of this class that the event handler needs to be supplied before the type can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your types immutable and validate on construction.

Something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(string aString, int anInt)
   {
     // Check for validity - throw exception if not valid

      ValidString = aString;
      ValidInt = anInt;
   }

   public string ValidString { get; private set; }
   public int ValidInt { get; private set; }
}
```

This ensures your entities/classes can never get into an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

Events are best used in situations where the number of subscribers may legitimately be anything from zero on up.  If the construction of an object will require that it have somewhere to send notifications, then the constructor should either receive an object that implements a notification interface or else a delegate which will perform the appropriate notification action.  If one uses a a delegate, it should not be added to an event list, but stored in its own field.  It may be worthwhile to sanity-check the interface or delegate to ensure it's not null, but in most cases there would be no reason for paranoia beyond that.